# Convergence of the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{i\phi(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I'd like to study the convergence of the integral
$$\int_0^\infty e^{i\phi(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t=\int_0^\infty \cos\phi(t) \, \mathrm dt + i\int_0^\infty\sin\phi(t) \, \mathrm dt$$
where $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is

- real valued,
- $C^2$,
- **Strictly** increasing, and
- **Strictly** convex

A well known example is the *Fresnel integral*

### $$\int_0^\infty e^{ix^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{3/2}}e^{i\pi/4}$$

Here of course we would have $\phi:t\mapsto t^2$. This integral is well known to be convergent. But will all such $\phi$ satisfying our 4 conditions produce a convergent integral? For example I played around with the integrals

$$\int_0^\infty \exp(i~e^x) \, \mathrm dx \text{ and } \int_0^\infty\exp(i~\Gamma(x+1)) \, \mathrm dx$$

And as far as I can tell, they are convergent. But how to deal with the problem generally? I thought about considering the sequence

$$a_n=\int_n^{n+1}e^{i\phi(t)}\mathrm{d}t$$

And trying to show that it is Cauchy, but I was unable to make much progress with bounding the terms. I mean for sure we can say that
$$|a_n|< 1$$
But clearly we need to do a lot better than that to guarantee convergence of the integral. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: For $\phi(x) = x$ (which satisfies all your condition), the integral does not converge;

Comment: I meant **strictly** increasing and convex.

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in this as a general topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillatory_integral

Comment: The condition is still not enough, while the $C^2$ condition and convexity are not necessary. For you to see why your conditions are not enough, take $\phi(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @Paresseux Nguyen $x\mapsto x+1/x$ is not strictly increasing!!

Comment: Doesn't mean anything. You can always modify the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: It's not about "gotcha you're wrong". I just show why your condition may fail.

Comment: If you want to, just modify it $(x+1)+1/(x+1)$ for example.