# $ \int_0^\infty \cos( \text{polynomial}(x)) dx $ -- generalized Fresnel integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am hoping to find an explicit evaluation of the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \cos(p(x)) dx
$$
and similarly
$$
\int_0^\infty \sin(p(x)) dx
$$
where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree greater than or equal to 2.  What I am hoping for is an explicit formula in terms of the coefficients of $p(x)$.

A particular special case is the limit of the [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) and I was hoping there is a generalization of that.  Perhaps there is not some simple evaluation in terms of known constants for a general polynomial.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452661/generalized-fresnel-integral-int-0-infty-sin-xp-rm-dx) is a question that I found related to this that solves a certain special case.

Comment: complete the square

Comment: There are answers in [integrals with coalescing saddles](https://dlmf.nist.gov/36.2)

Comment: There are only some very special circumstances in which the integral actually converges. I in fact already asked about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168290/convergence-of-the-integral-int-0-infty-ei-phit-mathrmdt)

Comment: @K.defaoite Unless I am mistaken, all the integrals of the form in the question do converge.  They arise from thinking of plane curves with non-constant polynomial curvature functions.  Since polynomials tend to +/- infinity eventually such curves spiral in towards a point.   That point has coordinates given by these integrals (where the polynomial in the question is the antiderivative of the given polynomial).